# boot problem after installing ubuntu 15.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, 15.04

I have purchased an `Asus N551jq laptop` and trying to install an Ubuntu 15.04 on it. I have modified my laptop with adding an SSD drive instead of my optical drive.

I tried installing Ubuntu 15.04 from a USB stick on my new system. The installation was smooth and I didn't get any strange error at all. After installation finished, I was able to boot to my Ubuntu with the USB-stick connected to my system. But whenever I remove the USB-stick from my computer and restart my computer, I get a black screen with a message:

```
reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media 
in selected  boot device and press a key
```

But after that, whenever I press ctrl+alt+del button system will boot into Ubuntu.

This is `sudo fdisk -l` result:

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 225142783 224092160 106.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  225142784 250068991  24926208  11.9G Linux swap
```

I wonder what the problem is?

**Update: link to [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12514917/)**

Comment: You probably installed grub to your USB stick  instead of /dev/sda. It can be fixed by Boot repair program.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have tried that. doesn't help. thanks for your comment btw.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve this problem by adjusting the UEFI settings.

Boot into BIOS  (in 99% of the cases pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>  or <kbd>Del</kbd> 
during boot splash works)
and check the boot order.

Select entry '**ubuntu**' to be the **first and default option** to **boot**.

If this solution doesn't work, reinstall GRUB bootloader.

To do this boot from ubuntu install media and execute :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt  
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi  
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done  
sudo chroot /mnt  
grub-install /dev/sda  
update-grub
```

Comment: sorry dude, that was the first thing I have tried. I have searched as much as possible and am somehow sure no one has reported such behavior elsewhere. And besides, I am well aware of stackexchange mechanism.

Comment: @OmidNN : I updated my answer with the instruction on how to reinstall the bootloader. Please try out ... hope that helps ! :)

Comment: dear @cl-netbox, thanks for your answer. But I have tried that before..